# Loading Images from a LevelDB in python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7, encoding, jpeg, leveldb

I am facing a problem with python (2.7) "strings".
I am using a LevelDB and want to load an image from the database and save it to disk (e.g., as test.jpeg).

To access the db I am using the `plyvel` package. I get the img data as follows:

```
img = db.get(str(id))
```

The problem is that LevelDB stores every value as byte string. Thus, `db.get()` returns a byte  string. If I try to write the img to disk

```
f = io.open('test.jpeg', 'wb')
f.write(img)
f.close()
```

and open it I afterwards I get something like:

> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xc3 0xbf

`c3 bf` is the UTF-8 encoding of `ff` in latin-1, which are the first bytes of JFIF's start of image marker.

How can I encode/decode the string so taht I can open the jpeg file? 
I tried bytearray(img) which did not work. Encoding /decoding the img string did not help at all.

=== EDIT ===

I am using now this sequence:

```
img = db.get(str(id))
img_decode_utf8 = img.decode('utf-8')
img_bytes = array.array('u', img_decode_utf8)
```

If I print `img_bytes` I get:

```
array('u', u'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\...
```

However, if I write it to disk, each byte is "zero extended". Hexdump:

```
00ff    0000    00d8    0000    00ff    0000    00e0    0000
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
img = db.get(str(hash_value))
img_bytes = img.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1')

with open('test.jpeg', 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(img_bytes)
```

I am quite sure that I tried this and it did not work in the first place..